# Output format of query object attributes

Tags: python, object, sqlalchemy

So I have generated a query object using sqlalchemy like so (where create_session() is a function I wrote):

```
sess = create_session(test_db)
q = sess.query(A).all()
```

Then, after creating this object (which is itself a list of objects)
I iterate over it to get information. Say I want the id attribute from each object in the list, I just do this.

```
for row in q:
    print row.id
```

This gives me output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

However, now I want to create a list of all ids. So, I do this.

```
ks = []
for row in q:
    ks.append(row.id)
```

Printing the list I get:

```
[1L, 2L, 3L, 4L]
```

Why is the formatting different? And is there any way to just have plain integers be added to my list? The ultimate goal is to create a dictionary with ids as keys and then the whole object (from the original list returned by my query) as a value. I could just use some string methods to get these down to plain integers but it would be easier if I could get them in the desired form directly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was as simple as applying the int() method to my id.

```
ks = []
for row in q:
    ks.append(int(row.id))
```

However, I am still unsure why the ids are returned in this odd format. Can anyone provide insight?